# Minimum number of generators for a gloablly generated sheaf over a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective curve over an algebraically closed field and $E$ be a globally generated locally free sheaf of rank $r$. Is it always possible to write $E$ as the quotient of $r+1$ copies of the structure sheaf
$\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus r+1}$?

Comment: Yes. More generally, if $\dim X=d$, you could do the same with $r+d$ generators.

Comment: @Mohan Could you please suggest an idea or a reference for this.

Comment: For the line bundle case, see Mumford's Curves on a surface; it si referred to as a theorem of Serre.

Comment: As usual, compute the dimension of the variety $Z\subset X\times \mathbb{G}(r+d,H^0(E)) $  consisting of pairs $(x,V)$ such that $V\rightarrow E_x$ is not surjective, and conclude that the projection $Z\rightarrow \mathbb{G}(r+d,H^0(E)) $  is not surjective.

Comment: @abx , Mohan : Thanks for the answer.